# Visual Workflow not running due to FLOW_ELEMENT_FAULT

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I'm pretty new to this Flow Designer, so that's out there...

I'm kicking off a Flow ([screencast.com/t/1BzgE0D7L](http://screencast.com/t/1BzgE0D7L)) with a Flow Trigger ([screencast.com/t/wDcb5TESKdwY](http://screencast.com/t/wDcb5TESKdwY)).

But when I look in the logs (with the "FINEST" setting for Workflow), all I see is this:

WF_FLOW_ACTION_BEGIN|09L140000008OIF
FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D30000000pgfe|30014000000CJWx|30114000000L5sK
FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END|4722aa29f56fcbd99f052848783148af128cde-7917|Webinar Updater
FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_BEGIN|1
FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|4722aa29f56fcbd99f052848783148af128cde-7917|Webinar Updater
FLOW_ELEMENT_FAULT|Element deferred|FlowRecordLookup|Campaign_Member_Lookup
FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|4722aa29f56fcbd99f052848783148af128cde-7917|Webinar Updater
FLOW_ELEMENT_FAULT|Element deferred|FlowRecordLookup|Lookup_Contact
FLOW_ELEMENT_FAULT|Element deferred|FlowRecordUpdate|Update_Contact

It fails at the first step. This is all the flow trigger is doing:
http://www.screencast.com/t/s5JXaGm4Ly

and this is what that first step is doing:
http://www.screencast.com/t/0CqLTqHop

The email doesn't even get sent. Any help??

Comment: Have you checked the campaign member lookup?  Is it returning null or something different to what the flow is expecting? Does the running used have access to the object./ fields?

Comment: I guess the first thing to ask is, how do I "check the campaign member lookup"? How do I output a variable to the debug log or anywhere else? yes, the user has access to campaigns.

Comment: Couple options: You can add a Screen element right after your Fast Lookup, and in the screen use a Display Text box to show the variable you are capturing your Campaign Member in. This may cause issues with the Flow Trigger nature of the flow though. Alternatively, you could create a Send Email element after the Fast Lookup and put the variable in the body of the email.

Comment: Also, I should point out that you have a loop, but your elements don't return to it at any point. Not sure if that was just because you were truncating the flow for the screenshot.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment: "your elements don't return to it". The campaign member lookup returns multiple campaign members (or should), loops through them, and if the CampaignMember.Status=Attended, creates a task.   Really appreciate your help -- I usually code. This thing is new to me. :)

Comment: Ok. I figured out the loop comment. I didn't realize a you actually had to have an element flow back into the loop to go to the next item in the collection. I set up screens to debug the new process, and it iterates through the campaign members fine. But when I do it through the flow trigger I still have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally got it working.

Thanks for the help from @markross__c!

The biggest hurdle was just understanding how flows work -- this was my first flow with any complexity. Maybe it's just me, but the docs on this are terrible (I found this video useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLvcJx2xssw).

Here's what I learned:

1. The last flow component that will run in a loop has to "return" back to the loop for the next element to run. I assumed anything running in the "path" from "next element" would be run, and I would start a new path with "end of loop".
2. #1 holds true even when you have a condition around the last component in a loop. If that last component might not run, the decision element must return back to the loop.
3. To debug a flow, use screens and $Flow.FaultMessage to see what's wrong.
4. You have to save your changes from the Designer in order to "preview" those changes (e.g. when you hit "Run" from the designer). Sounds stupid, but I assumed it would run what was on the screen...

Thanks again for your help, all. I could have written the code for this a lot faster than building this flow, but now that I've done it, I should be able to reduce the amount of code I have to write A LOT.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. There is learning curve with flow especially now with the headless/loop changes!